# Best way to get Facebook friend photos with Android Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

What is the best way to get all the profile pictures for a user's friends? Do I have to loop every Facebook friend or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your user has authenticated with your application, call the /friends endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=... Parse the result for the friend ids, and then you have the friend's image url which is in this format:

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=small
[image]

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square
[image: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square]

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=normal
[image: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=normal]

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large
[image: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large]